Google Timeline as a booking system
Im attempting to create a booking system with React Google Timeline and the issue is with regard to the Select Event which I use to edit the booking! data is retrieved from the database and loaded into the chart. As its not possible to store the record id in the chart, I use the starttime, which will be unique in my project, to query the database to get the id and then load the booking into a modal. the booking is then modified and save to the database. I then do another database call to get the full data for the chart and pass it back to the home page via props. At this point everything looks good and the chart has updated to show the new time. You can then click on other booking and get the correct booking. However if you now click on the modified booking you get the original timline data which and not the times indicated on the updated chart
I have produced a simplied project to demostrate my issue where you should modify the second booking only but use the first to test the Select Event is working
Home.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";
import TimeLine from "./TimeLine";

const Home = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const InitialData = [
    [
      { type: "string", id: "Day" },
      { type: "string", id: "Name" },
      { type: "string", id: "style", role: "style" },
      { type: "date", id: "Start" },
      { type: "date", id: "End" },
    ],
    [
      "1-April-2024",
      "G-ABCD",
      "blue",
      new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0),
      new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 30, 0),
    ],
    [
      "1-April-2024",
      "G-EGCF",
      "red",
      new Date(0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0),
      new Date(0, 0, 0, 17, 30, 0),
    ],
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(InitialData);
  }, []);

  const LoadTimeLine = (data) => {
    const UpdatedData = [
      [
        { type: "string", id: "Day" },
        { type: "string", id: "Name" },
        { type: "string", id: "style", role: "style" },
        { type: "date", id: "Start" },
        { type: "date", id: "End" },
      ],
      [
        "1-April-2024",
        "G-ABCD",
        "blue",
        new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0),
        new Date(0, 0, 0, 13, 30, 0),
      ],
    ];
    let temp = [];

    temp.push(data.day),
      temp.push(data.name),
      temp.push(data.color),
      temp.push(new Date(data.start)),
      temp.push(new Date(data.end)),
      UpdatedData.push(temp);

    setData(UpdatedData);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TimeLine data={data} LoadTimeLine={LoadTimeLine}></TimeLine>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;

TimeLine.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";
import EditBooking from "./EditBooking";

const TimeLine = ({ data, LoadTimeLine }) => {
  const [booking, setBooking] = useState([]);
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([
    {
      day: "",
      name: "",
      color: "",
      start: "",
      end: "",
    },
  ]);

  const handleEvent = (booking) => {
    setChartData(booking);
    setModalShow(true);
  };
  const hideModal = () => {
    setModalShow(false);
  };
  const loadNewData = (booking) => {
    LoadTimeLine(booking);
  };

  const chartEvents = [
    {
      eventName: "select",
      callback({ chartWrapper }) {
        const selectedItems = chartWrapper.getChart().getSelection();
        if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
          const selectedItem = selectedItems[0];
          const row = selectedItem.row + 1;
          const dataPoint = data[row];

          let booking = [];
          booking.push({
            day: dataPoint[0],
            name: dataPoint[1],
            color: dataPoint[2],
            start: dataPoint[3],
            end: dataPoint[4],
          });

          handleEvent(booking);
        }
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <EditBooking
        modalShow={modalShow}
        hideModal={hideModal}
        chartData={chartData}
        loadNewData={loadNewData}
      ></EditBooking>
      <Chart
        chartType="Timeline"
        data={data}
        width="100%"
        height="400px"
        options={{
          timeline: {
            colorByRowLabel: true,
          },
        }}
        chartEvents={chartEvents}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default TimeLine;

EditBooking.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";

const EditBooking = ({ modalShow, hideModal, chartData, loadNewData }) => {
  const [day, setDay] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  const [start, setStart] = useState("");
  const [end, setEnd] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setDay(chartData[0].day);
    setName(chartData[0].name);
    setColor(chartData[0].color);
    setStart(chartData[0].start);
    setEnd(chartData[0].end);
  }, [chartData]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const booking = { day, name, color, start, end };
    loadNewData(booking);
    hideModal();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={hideModal}
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton={hideModal}>
          <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="container">
            <h2>Edit Form</h2>
            <form>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="label1" className="form-label">
                  Day
                </label>
                <input
                  id="label1"
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  value={day}
                  onChange={(e) => setDay(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="label2" className="form-label">
                  Name
                </label>
                <input
                  id="label2"
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  value={name}
                  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="label3" className="form-label">
                  Color
                </label>
                <input
                  id="label3"
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  value={color}
                  onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="label4" className="form-label">
                  Time
                </label>
                <input
                  id="labe14"
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  value={start}
                  onChange={(e) => setStart(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="label6" className="form-label">
                  id
                </label>
                <input
                  id="label6"
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  value={end}
                  onChange={(e) => setEnd(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={hideModal}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Save
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default EditBooking;

